# Cleaner way to install and use Vue.js in Laravel without Starter kit (laravel/ui, breeze, jetstream)?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I want to start a project to work with `Laravel` and `Vue.js`.

I've looked up and almost all sites and tutorials show that I need a starter kit (`laravel/ui, breeze, jetstream`) to install Vue.js on Laravel.
But I prefer to be able to create myself the login, register, routes, etc.

Is there a **cleaner** way to install and use `Vue.js` without additional systems?

Comment: Well You can just manually install all the dependecies needed or just create a new local repository with fresh laravel app install then install the `laravel/breeze` then remove all the newly added files that you don't need.

Answer (score 0):

On a fresh laravel install, just go with

```
npm install vue@next
```

Then you can refer to the docs to [manually authenticate users](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authentication#authenticating-users)

You will just have to setup a blade template with a wrapper let's id it #app, and then in a js file

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
const app = createApp({

})   
app.mount("#app")
```

You will have to setup your Vite or Webpack to compile your javascript assets.